# Generalization of Fisher information for a discrete parameter

Tags: references, fisher-information

This is mainly a reference request.  There must be some generalizations of the concept of Fisher information for discrete (say, integer-valued) parameters, and of related results such as the Cramer-Rao bound (or information inequality). I have just never seen them.

Are there any good references, to the concept(s) itself, or to interesting applications?

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701347) on cardinality estimation uses the Cramér-Rao inequality in a context where the parameter is integer-valued (page 9, proposition 2.9). However, they seem to do some kind of transformation to transform their estimator $\hat \xi$ into $\xi^*$ to make it differentiable. I'm not sure I understand what they're doing exactly, and an answer to your question would probably help…

Comment: The generalization is the [Hammersley–Chapman–Robbins bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapman%E2%80%93Robbins_bound), but this bound seems to be too tight for any estimator: the variance decreases exponentially. See [my question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/471897/variance-of-an-integer-valued-parameter-estimator-for-poisson-distribution/471903) for an example.

Comment: But why in this [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.01064.pdf), page 5, eq.(1.6), the discrete Fisher information is directly defined? Is it wrong? Cause it seems okay to me.

Comment: I think the definition of Fisher Information in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) states this very clear: The $f(x|\theta)$ stands for pdf or pmf, deciding on whether it's continuous or discrete. Is it right? I think it's okay for me. But it seems the link by @Krivoi is some conflict to the result I agree? What do you think, kjetil b halvorsen?

Comment: @narip: I will look into this again, but note that I ask for a discrete (for example, integer) *parameter*, not *variable*. Maybe the misunderstanding is that in some fields the word parameter is used for variable? So, if the parameter is known to be an integer (for example a population size), then the differentiationnused in the usual definition makes no sense!

Comment: Oh, I see, I'm also interested in the case that the parameter is discrete(In this case, Cramer-Rao bound lose its effect...). Yes, you're right, the wiki link I gave just now is the discrete variable.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen did you eventually come to a satisfying conclusion?

Comment: @user: NO, I have thought about other things for a while ...