# Variance of an integer-valued parameter estimator for Poisson distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimators

Supposing I have a Poisson distributed random variable $X \sim \text{Poiss}(\lambda)$ with a parameter $\lambda$ that could take *integer values only*. Let $x$ be a single observation of a random variable. I could now get the estimate $\hat{\lambda}$ of the parameter by [maximizing the likelihood function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation):
$$
\hat{\lambda} = \arg\max_{\lambda \in \mathbb{N}}{ \log{p(x|\lambda)} }, \tag{1}
$$
where $p(x|\lambda)$ is the Poisson PDF. To get the estimator variance $\text{Var}(\hat{\lambda})$ I first calculate the estimator distribution as
$$
f(\hat{\lambda}|\lambda_0)=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{N}}{p(x|\lambda_0)\mathbf{1}_{\{\log{p(x|\hat{\lambda})} \geq \log{p(x|\lambda)}, \forall\lambda\in\mathbb{N}\}}}. \tag{2}
$$
Here $\lambda_0\in\mathbb{N}$ is the true parameter value and $\mathbf{1}_{\{\cdot\}}$ is equal to 1 if condition in brackets holds and 0 otherwise. Since I computed (2) I can easily get $\text{Var}(\hat{\lambda})$. But things get worse when I try to estimate the parameter using a sample $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ of the size $n$. In this case the estimator is
$$
\hat{\lambda} = \arg\max_{\lambda \in \mathbb{N}}{ \sum_{j=1}^{n}{\log{p(x_j|\lambda)}} }. \tag{3}
$$
Now the estimator PDF is
$$
f(\hat{\lambda}|\lambda_0)=\sum_{x_1,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb{N}}{p(x_1|\lambda_0)\cdot\ldots\cdot p(x_n|\lambda_0)\mathbf{1}_{\{\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\log{p(x_j|\hat{\lambda})}} \geq \sum_{j=1}^{n}{\log{p(x_j|\lambda)}}, \forall\lambda\in\mathbb{N}\}}}. \tag{4}
$$
There is no way to compute (4) for large $n$ (about $10^4$ in my case). So my questions are:

1. Can I somehow simplify (4) to break the sum into a product?
2. Are there some other ways to estimate the variance of the estimator (3)?

### Things that I've tried

First of all I've tried to estimate the variance using [Cramer-Rao bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) by taking the finite difference derivative:
$$
\text{Var}(\hat{\lambda}) = \left(n\mathbb{E}\left[(\log{p(x|\lambda_0+1)}-\log{p(x|\lambda_0))^2}\right]\right)^{-1}. \tag{5}
$$
As expected, that didn't work quite well: the variance in simulation was lower than this value.

Then I came across a more general [Hammersley–Chapman–Robbins bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapman%E2%80%93Robbins_bound). One can find that for my case the lower bound is (e.g. see [Dahiya R.C., Commun. Stat. - Theory Methods, 15(3), 709 (1986)])
$$
\text{Var}(\hat{\lambda}) = \left(e^{n/\lambda_0}-1\right)^{-1}. \tag{6}
$$
However, this bound turned out to be too tight and was unreachable for any estimator I could find due to exponential decrease of the bound with $n$ (the same problem stated in Dahiya's article).

Answer (score 4):

If you need the **exact** variance you're in trouble, I think. If not, progress can be made.

To start with, the monotone likelihood ratio property of exponential families means that $\hat\lambda$ is either the integer below the mean $\bar X$ or the integer above the mean.  The variance of $\bar X$ is $\lambda/n$.

Consider some ranges of ($n$,$\lambda$):

- If $\sqrt{\lambda/n}\gg 1$ then $\mathrm{var}[\hat\lambda]\approx \lambda/n$, since the reduction in variance caused by making $\hat\lambda$ an integer is small compared to the standard error of the mean.
- For slightly smaller $\lambda/n$, $\mathrm{var}[\hat\lambda]$ is a bit smaller than $\lambda/n$. We can write
  $$\mathrm{var}[\hat\lambda] \approx  \mathrm{var}[\bar X] - \mathrm{var}[\bar X-\hat\lambda]$$
  and approximate the second term by the variance of a $U[-0.5, 0.5]$
  $$\mathrm{var}[\hat\lambda] \approx  \mathrm{var}[\bar X] -1/12$$
  (this is the *opposite* of the Sheppard correction for rounding)
- The difficult case: $\lambda/n$ not far from 1. I think this needs actual calculation, but only over the relatively small number of $\hat\lambda$ values with non-negligible probability.
- At the far extreme, if $\sqrt{\lambda/n}\ll 1$, $\mathrm{var}[\hat\lambda]\approx 0$ (and even $n\mathrm{var}[\hat\lambda]\approx 0$), since $\hat\lambda=\lambda$ with very high probability.
  For example, if $\sqrt{\lambda/n}=1/10$, different integers are ten standard deviations apart, so it will be very unlikely for the closest integer to $\bar X$ not to be the true $\lambda$.

Comment: Can I interpret the last option as follows: for a continuous-valued parameter MLE asymptotically gives a normally distributed estimator, which I can then approximate to a discrete distribution by turning the PDF into a histogram with bin centers located at the discrete values?

Comment: Yes, but the condition is stronger than just 'continuous-valued'.  For some other type of distribution it might be possible for the discrete MLE to not just be a rounded continuous MLE, but for Poisson it will be.

Comment: Can I get some examples of a discrete parameter MLE? Is it like the one from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40319/maximum-likelihood-estimate-of-hypergeometric-distribution-parameter)?

Comment: Yes, balls in urns are a classic example where the parameter is discrete. Another two are from ecology:  estimating the population of a type of animal or the number of distinct species of animal. Often, though, you're in the first situation in the answer, where the discreteness can be ignored